# Trouble understanding sum and product of probability distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Having trouble understanding where can we use the sum and product of probability distributions. Could someone please provide me with a real-life scenario? I think this is what I need to understand the formula.

Also without finding any real-life scenarios on the Internet just looking at my notes I currently doesn't find it very logical that both for sum and product the probabilities are multiplied. Is there some mistake in my notes?

Given that X and Y are both discrete probability distributions

The sum of $(X,  P(X))$ and $(Y,  P(Y)$)

$X+Y$ is $(Z, P(Z)) = {(z_k, p(z_k))}$, where 
$z_k = x_i + y_j$ $(i=1,2,...,n;j=1,2,...,m)$ and$ p(z_k)= p(x_i)*p(y_j)$.

The product of $(X,  P(X))$ and $(Y,  P(Y))$

$X*Y$ is $(Z, P(Z)) = {(z_k, p(z_k))}$, where
$z_k=x_i*y_j(i=1,2,...,n;j=1,2,...,m)$ and $p(z_k)= p(x_i)*p(y_j)$.

To make my question clearer: In what cases can we use the sum and product formula for discrete probability distribution?

Comment: First thing: you never actually sum or multiply the distributions. It's the variables that get summed or multiplied. The distributions get convoluted.

Comment: @Raskolnikov's comment is the most important piece of information on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent discrete random variables:

a) **Sum of Discrete Random Variable**:
Let $Z=X+Y$ and further $X=k$ and $Z=z$. You can only have $Z=z$ when $Y=z-k$. So,

$P(Z=z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=+\infty} P(X=k)P(Y=z-k)$. This is a convolution operation.

Example: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Bernoulli random variables:

So,

$P(Z = 0) = P(X + Y = 0) = P(X = 0)P(Y = 0) = (1-p)^2$
$P(Z = 1) = P(X = 0)P(Y = 1) + P(X = 1)P(Y = 0)= (1 -p)p + p(1 -p) = 2p(1 -p)$
$P(Z = 2) = P(X = 1)P(Y = 1) = p^2$

$Z$ has a binomial distribution with $n=2$

$P(Z=z)=\binom{2}{z}p^z(1-p)^{2-z}$

b) **For product**, you can try it yourself based on above.

Comment: This makes sense. If you could add some simple example where these two formulas can be used in real life - that would help a lot. Some simple sample exercise kind of example.

Comment: @ArturKäpp see above where I have added a bernoulli example. It's well known that adding independent bernoulli random variables leads to a binomial distribution.

Comment: I think I finally understood something - Thank you!

Comment: @ArturKäpp great :-)